How to avoid centering caption by default?
The caption centering is quite annoying, is it possible to avoid it?
My problem comes when in my code
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf,
        justification=raggedright]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Calzada del Gigante, Condado de Artrim (Irlanda del Norte)}
        \label{img1}
    }
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Alan Arnold Griffith(1893-1963)}
        \label{img2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The centering of the captions makes it readability really poor.

Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Your MWE isn't using subfig, so the captions should be 5 cm wide.  Unless twemojis (whatever that is) is doing it.  Oh, and you are aligning the centers, which include the captions.

@JohnKormylo Why do you say its aligning the centres? There's no non-default alignment inside the \parboxes, is there?

If I run your code with \usepackage[draft]{graphicx} because only you have those images, the captions are neither narrowed nor centred but take the entire width of the \parbox and minipage respectively. The images are likewise aligned left. Please use standard images or draft in examples and ensure that your example produces the output you show.

@JohnKormylo but I'm aligning the figure, not especially the captions. Even if I delete the \centering line, the captions still happen to be centered.

@cfr I think there isn't any default alignment inside the parbox , but the captions are unexplicably center aligned.

By default, the content in minipage or \parbox is centered on the baseline. Use \parbox[t]{5cm} and \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm} to get the images aligned.

As for your new question: I don't get the result you show from the code you show. Can you make sure that they fit together?

@jlab Vertically, yes. But not horizontally. And there's nothing here to make them narrow.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz true, I am using documentclass{amsart} instead of documentclass{article}

With amsart you should be aware that it uses \captionindent on either side of the caption, so as to make it not using the full text width.
You can locally set it to zero, for the purpose of the specific figure.
However:

you should specify the width of the figures, rather than the height;
you need to use the correct syntax and it's unclear why using \parbox for one figure and minipage for the other;
it's \parbox[t]{5cm}, not the other way around;
a space after “Griffith” is needed.

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Your code}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \parbox[t]{5cm}{
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Calzada del Gigante, Condado de Artrim (Irlanda del Norte)}
        \label{img1}
    }
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Alan Arnold Griffith(1893-1963)}
        \label{img2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\section{Edited code}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\setlength{\captionindent}{0pt}

\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Calzada del Gigante, Condado de Artrim (Irlanda del Norte)}
  \label{img1}
\end{minipage}% <--- avoid a spurious space
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Alan Arnold Griffith (1893-1963)}
  \label{img2}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}



If i correctly understand what you after, than you only need to align top of figures, like this:

For caption I suggest to use caption package (for nicer caption formatting), figure are aligned by aligning\parbox and minipage to their tops (it is not clear why you not use for both images the same box):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf,
            justification=raggedright]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \parbox[t]{5cm}{ % <--- observe t
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Calzada del Gigante, Condado de Artrim (Irlanda del Norte)}
        \label{img1}
    }
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm} % <--- observe t
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Alan Arnold Griffith (1893-1963)}
        \label{img2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Addendum:

For caption formatting is used caption package. It offer many possibilities (see package documentation).
For boxes I would use the same box at both figures.
For figures width I would exploit as much as is possible width. For example, 0.48\textwidth for each figure. By this captions can be placed in two text lines
Since both images has the same size, using Gin keys enable  bit shorter code:

\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf,
            justification=raggedright]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=44mm}
    \parbox[t]{0.48\textwidth}{
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Calzada del Gigante, Condado de Artrim (Irlanda del Norte)}
        \label{img1}
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox[t]{0.48\textwidth}{
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Alan Arnold Griffith (1893-1963)}
        \label{img2}
   }
\end{figure}

\end{document}


(red lines indicate page layout)

Maybe make the minipage/parbox wide enough for the images so that the caption isn't so much off-centre?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I'm not sure what is OP intention. I would do so :-)

Whatever the OP's intention is, I hope its not offccentred captions and asymmetric margins :)
